# user signup form not working in internet explorer 9

Tags: php, html, internet-explorer-9

at my wits end with a form issue in internet explorer 9 - The form works fine in all other browsers and even works in IE9 on my offline server but when online you submit the form and it just does nothing. the form empties

link to the actual form here:

http://www.bloggabase.com/account/signup/blog

any help would be massively appreciated. the code handling the form is all PHP

Comment: Works fine for me in IE9

Answer (score 1):

works here as far as i can tell. try clearing your cache e.c.t.

Comment: thanks for the responses. glad to see it is working for at least some users.. when I submit the form on the first page the page just refreshes (like it hasnt processed any data) I'm running IE9 on a windows 7 PC and I have enabled all cookies and set windows defaults to lowest level.

Comment: sorry pressed enter too soon! really;y appreciate the responses. could someone just confirm after pressing next they are able to go through the whole form? thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

Its working absolutely fine in IE9 , just try emptying your cache and also check your internet spped , because some pages do not open properly in less speed .